# Why is my Stripe API key not working in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments, credentials

This question has been asked but it seems the format for using Stripe Checkout has changed, as well as the format for encrypting credentials (secrets.yml to credentials.yml)

So in development we've been using the test keys and had no problem. but now that we've deployed to Heroku it breaks every time we try to navigate to Stripe Checkout. The error in Heroku logs seems pretty straightforward:

```
021-01-27T15:41:02.784429+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-01-27T15:41:02.784365 #4]  INFO -- : [88208302-394a-4144-b0d7-61fc69369ce7] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 379)
2021-01-27T15:41:02.785456+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2021-01-27T15:41:02.785380 #4] FATAL -- : [88208302-394a-4144-b0d7-61fc69369ce7]
2021-01-27T15:41:02.785459+00:00 app[web.1]: [88208302-394a-4144-b0d7-61fc69369ce7] Stripe::AuthenticationError (No API key provided. Set your API key using "Stripe.api_key = <API-KEY>". You can generate API keys from the Stripe web interface. See https://stripe.com/api for details, or email support@stripe.com if you have any questions.):
```

I run EDITOR=vim rails credentials:edit to edit credentials.yml.enc

in there I have:

```
aws:
  access_key_id: xxx
  secret_access_key: xxx

stripe:
  stripe_secret_key: sk_live_xxx
  stripe_publishable_key: pk_live_xxx

secret_key_base: xxx
```

in my stripe.rb file I have:

```
Rails.configuration.stripe = {
    :publishable_key => Rails.application.credentials.dig(:stripe, :stripe_publishable_key),
    :secret_key => Rails.application.credentials.dig(:stripe, :stripe_secret_key)

}


Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]
```

When I drop into rails console as well as rails console --environment=production and check Stripe.api_key
it perfectly returns the exact stripe secret key. I have no idea why the error says no Stripe API key provided. What am I not understanding? This is the final step to finish my first 'professional' web app (online store for a friend).

Comment: Which version of Rails are you deploying? There has been changes in encrypted credentials between 5 and 6. The root cause points to `Rails.application.credentials.dig(:stripe, :stripe_secret_key)` not being set in production or maybe the master key isn't set correctly. That depends on the Rails version. If you drop into `heroku console` and see what `Rails.application.credentials.stripe[:stripe_secret_key]` returns, that will be a good thing to debug (note the syntax difference just to be as close to the Rails docs as possible).

Comment: @ v3nkman thanks for the response! I'm on Rails 6.0.3.4. I used heroku console and checked Rails.application.credentials.stripe which returned nil, while the same command in dev console returned the keys. How do I set them in production?

Comment: Have you set the RAIILS_MASTER_KEY config in heroku? That's

`heroku config:set RAILS_MASTER_KEY=ABC123`

Rails 6 and heroku needs that to decrypt the file

Comment: I think that's assuming that the master key file hasn't been added to the repo which isn't recommended.

Comment: You can check the env. vars for heroku production with `heroku config`

Answer (score 0):

I got it! Like v3nkman suggested, I checked the heroku console for  `Rails.application.credentials.stripe`. It was returning nothing, while the dev console was returning the keys. It turns out I had set two env variables on Heroku when we initially deployed it: `PUBLISHABLE_KEY` and `SECRET_KEY`. but the `stripe.api_key` in the Stripe.rb file was pointing to `Rails.application.credentials.dig(:stripe, :stripe_secret_key)`. Which was null in Heroku. So I changed stripe.rb to

```
Rails.configuration.stripe = {
    :publishable_key => ENV['PUBLISHABLE_KEY'],
    :secret_key => ENV['SECRET_KEY']

}
Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]
```

Initially it didn't work, but that was because the Javascript request from the front end was still using a test key. Once I changed that to the live key, it worked

Comment: Nice! Glad it worked out. I think a goal for the future is to have the credentials managed in one place, but using heroku env vars will do the trick.